# s3.putObject(params).promise() does not upload file, but successfully executes then() callback

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I had pretty long number of attempts to put a file in S3 bucket, after which I have to update my model.

I have following code (note that I have tried commented lines too. It works neither with comments nor without it.)

**The problem observed:**
Everything in the first `.then()` block (`successCallBack()`) gets successfully executed, but I do not see result of `s3.putObject()`.

The bucket in question is public, no access restrictions. It used to work with sls offline option, then because of it not working in AWS I had to make lot of changes and managed to make successCallback() work which does the database work successfully. However, file upload still doesn't work.

**Some questions:**

While solving this, the real questions I am pondering / searching are,

- Is lambda supposed to return something? I saw AWS docs but they have fragmented code snippets.
- Putting `await` in front of `s3.putObject(params).promise()` does not help. I see samples with and without await in front of things that have AWS Promise() function call. Not sure which ones are correct.
- What is the correct way when you have chained async functions to accomplish within one lambda function?

**UPDATE:**

```
var myJSON = {}
const createBook = async (event) => {

    let bucketPath = "https://com.xxxx.yyyy.aa-bb-zzzzzz-1.amazonaws.com"
    let fileKey = //file key
    let path = bucketPath + "/" + fileKey;

    myJSON = {
      //JSON from headers
    }

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    let buffer = Buffer.from(event.body, 'utf8');

    var params = {Bucket: 'com.xxxx.yyyy', Key: fileKey, Body: buffer, ContentEncoding: 'utf8'};

    let putObjPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise();

    putObjPromise
    .then(successCallBack())
    .then(c => {
      console.log('File upload Success!');
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: "Success!!!"
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {   
        let str = "File upload /  Creation error:" + err;
        console.log(str);
        return {
          statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
          body: str
        }
    });
}

const successCallBack = async () => {
  console.log("Inside success callback - " + JSON.stringify(myJSON))  ;
  const { myModel } = await connectToDatabase()
  console.log("After connectToDatabase")
  const book = await myModel.create(myJSON)

  console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: are you sure `putObject()` isnt working? Adding a new item will be eventual consistent, and hence it may not appear right away. May be worth double checking after 20 sec or so.

Comment: also....you are invoking the callback, not referencing it in your code. you should do something like `pubObjPromise.then(successCallBack).then( #handle return from successCB)`

Comment: successCallBack() works successfully, It is defined at the bottom of the code. I see all logs from successCallBack() too. I have tried it for entire day and the bucket is still empty.

Comment: pass the function reference `successCallBack` not the invocation (ie `successCallBack(params)`

Comment: I put  putObjPromise .then(successCallBack) but it did not execute it at all. No errors in logs.

Comment: Try `.then(() => successCallBack(myJSON))`.

Comment: Is it possible that you are timing out on the putObject job now? Set the timeout to less than the lambda timeout to be sure

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - nope, it didn't even execute successCallBack.

Comment: @LostJon total timeout for lambda is set to 30 seconds prior to this test.

Comment: In that case, the promise returned by `s3.putObject(...).promise()` doesn't fulfill. If the catch hander is also not executed, then the promise doesn't settle at all - ie it neither fulfills nor throws.

Comment: Lambda is still set to less than your code... So if your error is a timeout, then your problem is likely with the s3 putObject call

Comment: Also, to verify...you will want to block your code using await...or call the event callback when asynchronous processing is done

Comment: @LostJon I didn't get which timeout you are talking about. The visible ones I introduced myself (they were defaults earlier). I put 30 seconds on total lambda execution which is much more. Whatever value I put there, it simply exhausts that value in doing database work but no file uploading.

Comment: Do the await on that .promise()...I think you will see your error then

Comment: Just updated my code which works great with sls offline without await against s3.putObject(params).promise(). Even S3 file upload works with RDS record update.

Comment: On AWS, this version returns without waiting for a timeout. No upload. No successCallBack().

Comment: Adding ´return putObjPromise;' at the end results in timeout on AWS. Works locally, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got this to work. My code worked already in sls offline setup.

**What was different on AWS endpoint?**

What I observed on console was the fact that my lambda was **set to run under VPC.**

When I chose **No VPC**, it worked. I do not know if this is the best practice. There must be some security advantage obtained by functions running under VPC.

I came across this huge [explanation about VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/) but I could not find anything related to S3.

The code posted in the question currently runs fine on AWS endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If the lambda is running in a VPC then you would need a VPC endpoint to access a service outside the vpc. S3 would be outside the VPC. Perhaps if security is an issue then creating a VPC endpoint would solve the issue in a better way. Also, if security is an issue, then perhaps adding a policy (or using the default AmazonS3FullAccess policy) to the role that the lambda is using, then the S3 bucket wouldn't need to be public.

Comment: +1 great explanation. While my work is progressing, this setup still gives me 502 error in Postman. Despite the fact that I am returning 200 from all success paths. Lambda is not somehow returning my JSON from then() blocks.

Comment: I haven't tried handling the promise in this way so I'm not sure.  Just as a test maybe try an await to see if the lambda is exiting before the then() is getting executed.  Just a thought.